# Well-formedness condition for inductive types

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, type-theory, dependent-type

I work on implementing a simple dependently typed language. I want to implement inductive types there. However, I want them to be well formed. From what I've seen in Coq not all types are acceptable. What can I read about them? Could give a simple enough well-formedness condition which I can use?

Comment: "simple, dependently-typed, inductive types": choose 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Martin's answer, you can try the "British school":

- Altenkirch, McBride & McKinna [Why Dependent Types Matter](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/publ/ydtm.pdf)
- Goguen, McBride & McKinna [Eliminating Dependent Pattern-Matching](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/99.pdf)

I'm sure that by this point you've been told to read Ulf Norrel's PhD dissertation. In fact pretty much any paper by Ulf is useful in this regard.

Answer (score 6):

Inductive types have been studied heavily and many variants exist. A well-known introduction to inductive definitions is

- P. Aczel, An Introduction to Inductive Definitions

which was originally published in the indispensable Handbook of Mathematical Logic, but is now available online stand-alone. An introduction to inductive types is

- T. Coquand, P. Dybjer, [Inductive Definitions and Type Theory: an Introduction](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/ESSLLI94.pdf).

The theory of inductive definitions for Coq was first (?) approached in

- F. Pfenning, C. Paulin-Mohring, [Inductively defined types in the Calculus of Constructions](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2907&context=compsci),

I don't know to what extend modern Coq has diverged from what's described in that paper. Either way, none of those is easy reading. You're probably better off to look at a Coq manual and copy the well-formedness conditions imposed there.